# How to get rich text formatting from asana task API

Tags: asana

Asana added rich text formatting in June 2014 (https://blog.asana.com/2014/06/rich-text/)

How do you get the formatting metadata from the Asana API?

For example, if I fill in a task description with:

---

some **bold** text. some *italic* text

a list

- foo
- bar
- sublist

  - a
  - b
  - c
  - baz

---

The API returns the following for the note field, which excludes any formatting info:

```
"notes":"some bold text. some italic text\n\na list\n\nfoo\n\nbar\n\nsublist \na\nb\nc\nbaz"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not currently support rich text formatting via the API. *However* if you're feeling adventurous, we are currently *working* on this support, and you can try it out by using html_notes (for tasks) and html_text (for stories). You can request them using `?opt_fields=html_notes`, for example.

Note however that this is still very experimental/early support. If the parser doesn't like the HTML you post, it just strips everything back to plaintext. So this is really only if you're feeling particularly adventurous - otherwise, I'd wait until we release full-fledged public support for it, with documentation and everything.

Comment: To update the field, should I set the "notes" field with html or should I set the "html_notes" field?

Comment: You would also want to set the `html_notes` field with HTML - it'll be stripped in `notes`. And even with `html_notes` not all HTML is considered valid, so it's a bit tricky to use.

Comment: Disappointing: If you use `opt_fields=`, you can't use `opt_expand=`

Answer (score 3):

Is this still something "experimental"? I didn't want to post an answer but it won't let me comment the existing answer. So far I have found:
Acceptable
    `<b>`
    `<ul>`
    `<li>`
Not acceptable:
    `<h4>`
    `<p>`
    `<div>`
    `<section>`
    `<br>`

Any other suggestions for something to do a linebreak? Back in the day, I was using Wufoo to directly create tasks in Asana and it formatted it with a bold heading and then regular text for each entry data. I am trying to achieve this on my own without going that route because I am also updating a database when I receive the form submission. Any ideas on how to format (only the most basic of formatting)?

Comment: I've discovered that you can use `\n` in order to initiate line breaks. `<ol>` is also an accepted value btw.

Comment: Also, you can use `<code>` if you want to do monospace font and `<u>` to do underlines. The only thing I'm unsure of based on their [Rich Text Formatting](https://asana.com/guide/help/fundamentals/text#gl-rich-text) docs would be the indenting... but then I don't think that's important for API-based task creation.